# linux: Discard dirty pages for block device (on usb disconnect)

Tags: usb-drive, block-device, buffer

When forcefully removing a USB device on linux while there are outstanding writes to the device the kernel log fills up with

```
blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdg, sector 50618368
Buffer I/O error on dev sdg, logical block 6327555, lost async page write
[...]
```

messages and USB device resets:

```
usb 4-2: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
```

I assume async page write refers to dirty pages in the buffer cache (write-back caching). 
It appears as if the kernel tries again for each dirty page, which takes a long time. All processes using the device hang.

**Is there any way to tell the kernel, the block device `/dev/sdg` is gone and is not going to come back - please drop all dirty pages for this block device?**

Note: This would probably apply to any type of block device as well.

Comment: How is the media being initially mounted. What file system type?

Comment: It's not mounted at all. Just writing random data to the device via dd directly.